# Pig - Structure formatting to generate JSON file

Tags: json, apache-pig

I'm working on some address data which needs to be formatted to generate a JSON file. I'm able to get my data into below format

```
Y: { name: chararray, { ( address: { ( street: chararray,city: chararray,state: chararray,zip: chararray ) } ) } }
```

And my data looks like

```
( jas, { ( { ( streetname1,city1,state1,zip1 ) } ) } )
( sou, { ( { ( streetname2,city2,state2,zip2 ) } ) } )
( sri, { ( { ( streetname3,city3,state3,zip3 ) } ) } )
```

But my required format is

```
Y: { name: chararray, address: { ( street: chararray,city: chararray,state: chararray,zip: chararray ) } }
```

and the data should look like

```
(jas, { ( streetname1,city1,state1,zip1 ) } )
(sou, { ( streetname2,city2,state2,zip2 ) } )
(sri, { ( streetname3,city3,state3,zip3 ) } )
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your address column is wrapped with one extra Bag, `Flattening` the address column would help to achieve the expected output.
Can you try this?

```
Z = FOREACH Y GENERATE name,FLATTEN($1);
DUMP Z;
```

Mostly the above command will work, incase if it doesn't work, please paste your original input data and also your pig script.